# How to automatically log user out when server is restarted?

Tags: python, django

Even when I restart my Django server, my user is logged in. Is there a quick way to log my user out automatically when I quit the server?

I tried 
    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
and it doesn't do anything

Thanks!

Comment: why would you do this ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm just in a development phase where I start/end the server a lot and it would be convenient. Rather, do you know a way to log out the user after some minutes of inactivity?

Comment: answer is in the duplicate.